# Best way to dynamically build a list of item in a Flutter widget

Tags: flutter

The code provided below creates and returns a list of children after calling the function `buildChildren` however it's usually not recommended to return widgets from a function (source: https://dcm.dev/docs/rules/flutter/avoid-returning-widgets).

I assume there's a better technique for doing this but I'm unfamiliar with what I have to search/know to get there. So is there an alternative to this approach?

```dart
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:flutter/widgets.dart';

enum IntrinsicResponsiveRowColumnType {
  ROW,
  COLUMN,
}

class IntrinsicResponsiveRowColumn extends StatelessWidget {
  const IntrinsicResponsiveRowColumn({
    super.key,
    this.children = const [],
    required this.layout,
    this.rowMainAxisAlignment = MainAxisAlignment.start,
    this.rowMainAxisSize = MainAxisSize.max,
    this.rowCrossAxisAlignment = CrossAxisAlignment.center,
    this.rowTextDirection,
    this.rowVerticalDirection = VerticalDirection.down,
    this.rowTextBaseline,
    this.columnMainAxisAlignment = MainAxisAlignment.start,
    this.columnMainAxisSize = MainAxisSize.max,
    this.columnCrossAxisAlignment = CrossAxisAlignment.center,
    this.columnTextDirection,
    this.columnVerticalDirection = VerticalDirection.down,
    this.columnTextBaseline,
    this.rowSpacing,
    this.columnSpacing,
    this.rowPadding = EdgeInsets.zero,
    this.columnPadding = EdgeInsets.zero,
  });
  final List<IntrinsicResponsiveRowColumnItem> children;
  final IntrinsicResponsiveRowColumnType layout;
  final MainAxisAlignment rowMainAxisAlignment;
  final MainAxisSize rowMainAxisSize;
  final CrossAxisAlignment rowCrossAxisAlignment;
  final TextDirection? rowTextDirection;
  final VerticalDirection rowVerticalDirection;
  final TextBaseline? rowTextBaseline;
  final MainAxisAlignment columnMainAxisAlignment;
  final MainAxisSize columnMainAxisSize;
  final CrossAxisAlignment columnCrossAxisAlignment;
  final TextDirection? columnTextDirection;
  final VerticalDirection columnVerticalDirection;
  final TextBaseline? columnTextBaseline;
  final double? rowSpacing;
  final double? columnSpacing;
  final EdgeInsets rowPadding;
  final EdgeInsets columnPadding;
  bool get isRow => layout == IntrinsicResponsiveRowColumnType.ROW;
  bool get isColumn => layout == IntrinsicResponsiveRowColumnType.COLUMN;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    if (layout == IntrinsicResponsiveRowColumnType.ROW) {
      return IntrinsicHeight(
        child: Padding(
          padding: rowPadding,
          child: Row(
            mainAxisAlignment: rowMainAxisAlignment,
            mainAxisSize: rowMainAxisSize,
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
            textDirection: rowTextDirection,
            verticalDirection: rowVerticalDirection,
            textBaseline: rowTextBaseline,
            children: buildChildren(children, true, rowSpacing),
          ),
        ),
      );
    }

    return IntrinsicHeight(
      child: Padding(
        padding: columnPadding,
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: columnMainAxisAlignment,
          mainAxisSize: columnMainAxisSize,
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
          textDirection: columnTextDirection,
          verticalDirection: columnVerticalDirection,
          textBaseline: columnTextBaseline,
          children: buildChildren(children, false, columnSpacing),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  /// Logic to construct widget [children].
  static List<Widget> buildChildren(
    List<IntrinsicResponsiveRowColumnItem> children,
    bool rowColumn,
    double? spacing,
  ) {
    // Sort ResponsiveRowColumnItems by their order.
    final childrenHolder = <IntrinsicResponsiveRowColumnItem>[...children]
      ..sort(
        (a, b) {
          return rowColumn
              ? a.rowOrder.compareTo(b.rowOrder)
              : a.columnOrder.compareTo(b.columnOrder);
        },
      );

    // Add padding between widgets..
    final widgetList = <Widget>[];
    for (var i = 0; i < childrenHolder.length; i++) {
      widgetList.add(childrenHolder[i].copyWith(rowColumn: rowColumn));
      if (spacing != null && i != childrenHolder.length - 1) {
        widgetList.add(
          Padding(
            padding: rowColumn
                ? EdgeInsets.only(right: spacing)
                : EdgeInsets.only(bottom: spacing),
          ),
        );
      }
    }

    return widgetList;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, The recommended pattern as mentioned by link in your question is to separate widgets from each other.

```
class ChildrenBuilder extends StatelessWidget{

    List<IntrinsicResponsiveRowColumnItem> children;
    bool rowColumn;
    double? spacing;

ChildrenBuilde({super.key, required this.children, required this.rowColumn, this.spacing});

@override
Widget build(BuildContext context){

    return your custom widget... 
}
}
```

in your big widget

```
class MyWidget extends StatelessWidget{

@override
Widget build(BuildContext context){
   return Column(
     children:[
         childrenBuilder(.... give it its arguments)
        ]
    );
     }
}
```

Although that requires some effort, but it's more efficient and cleaner than returning your custom widget from a helper method.

but why?

This is because, suppose your custom widget is a stateful widget that changes it's state, **in each time this widget change its state the framework recall the build method which surround that widget** which is so expensive.

if you have already separated this widget the framework calls its build method (less code get executed).

**Example:**

in your code what happen if `childrenBuilder` changed its state

The framework call the build method that surround `childrenBuilder`, this build method belong to the big widget (*more code get executed*).

in separation: The framework call the build method of the `childrenBuilder` because it has one, no need to rebuild it's parent(*less code get executed*).

but there's a term that must be mentioned which is Complexity (not Big O just code Complexity *Software Architecture Complexity*), Avoid needless Complexity, not every widget need to be separated. usually, this decision can be made according to widget simplicity.

Hope it helps you.

Comment: Thanks for your reply! I've tried this solution but unfortunately, it just moves the problem to the ChildrenBuilder widget.

Comment: @Phil mainly what's the problem that has been moved, you didn't mentioned any problem in your question, what we are trying to do is some enhancements not solving a specific problem, your code in either cases should run and produce the expected results.